# What happened to Buddy (Jack Black's character) in Community?

Tags: character, community

In Season 1 Episode 13: "Investigative Journalism" of Community, Buddy manages to include himself in the study group, having been sat unnoticed in the Spanish class all year.

He later (after being kicked out of the study group and being allowed back in) decides to join the "cool group". Considering that Starburns was also in that group, yet was seen to still be in the same Spanish class as the study group, was there any explanation as to why Buddy was no longer seen in the class?

Obviously out-of-universe, it would have been expensive to hire Jack Black to sit at the back of the class with no lines, so he was obviously just no longer included in the show, but **was there ever an in-universe explanation as to why he was never seen again?**

Did he simply go back to being unnoticed in the back of the class? Or did he drop out of the Spanish class/Greendale?

Comment: As far as I remember, there wasn't any explanation involving what happened to Buddy.

Comment: i guess it was just a one shot deal. Where he desperately wants to join the study-group, and despite his irritating behavior is eventually accepted. However he joins a cooler study group that includes Star-Burns and is led by Owen Wilson in a cameo when he finds out they voted him in..and that's all that's written about his character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No

#### No in-universe explanation

Buddy is never seen or mentioned again in-universe so we simply don't know exactly what his fate was. He either dropped out or graduated or simply never crossed paths with the study group again.

The Community wikia page for [Buddy Austin](http://community-sitcom.wikia.com/wiki/Buddy_Austin) confirms that the episode "Investigative Journalism" was the only and final appearance of the character.

#### Buddy has always been unnoticed

It has already established that Buddy has gone unnoticed for an entire semester of being in the same class so its not too much of a stretch to have him go back to being completely unnoticed.

#### Not the only character with a single appearance

There are also plenty of other [characters who only have a single appearance](http://community-sitcom.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Single_Appearance) and are never heard from or seen again, including Owen Wilson's character in the very same episode as the unnamed leader of "the cool group".